Manhwa about a blonde girl who gets adopted to replace a duke's cursed daughter
I'm looking for a manhwa I read some time last year. I think I read it around December and it only had 20 chapters then.
It's about a girl who gets adopted to replace the duke's daughter, who has a curse, and they all hate her for no good reason at all. They transfer the curse to the female lead which, causes her to die, but she goes back to the past and plans to run away from the family. Her stepfather was a war hero and her stepmother was previously a saint.
I don't really remember what all the characters look like, but I think the female lead has blonde hair and I know that her mother has blonde hair. I don't know what the cover looked like.
It's not Death Is the Only Ending for the Villainess AKA Villains Are Destined to Die.

The step mother had white hair not blonde

by step mother, do you mean the adoptive mother?

Yes it her adoptive mother aka the wife of the duke
